# Show that $(a + b)^4 + (a + c)^4 + (a + d)^4 + (b + c)^4 + (b + d)^4 + (c + d)^4 \le 6$ for $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, alternative-proof, nonlinear-optimization, sum-of-squares-method

For $a, b, c, d \in \Bbb R$ such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$, show that $$(a + b)^4 + (a + c)^4 + (a + d)^4 + (b + c)^4 + (b + d)^4 + (c + d)^4 \le 6.$$

The answer uses the mysterious identity $$(a + b)^4 + (a + c)^4 + (a + d)^4 + (b + c)^4 + (b + d)^4 + (c + d)^4 + (a - b)^4 + (a - c)^4 + (a - d)^4 + (b - c)^4 + (b - d)^4 + (c - d)^4 = 6(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2.$$

But this just comes out of the blue. Are there any other solutions?

Edit (for those who say this is lacking context): This comes from the beginning of a book named *Algebraic Inequalities* (not in English). After the preface to the first chapter, where the author introduced that many inequalities can be proved by using the non-negativity of $x^2$, this is the first example (without developing any other methods yet). Then the author notes: the reader is supposed to memorize identities like that.

Comment: More information about the book?

Comment: @zyx Really? The book is in Chinese!

Comment: That was not stated in the question.  Anyway, is the book on the internet?

Comment: @zyx It's available here, on a Chinese website: http://vdisk.weibo.com/s/ahlSXVCUjkm8T

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(a+b)^4+(a-b)^4=2a^4+12a^2b^2+2b^2$. Hence
$\begin{align}(a + b)^4 &+ (a + c)^4 + (a + d)^4 + (b + c)^4 + (b + d)^4 + (c + d)^4\\
 &+ (a - b)^4 + (a - c)^4 + (a - d)^4 + (b - c)^4 + (b - d)^4 + (c - d)^4\\
&=6(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)+12(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2d^2+d^2a^2+a^2c^2+b^2d^2)\\
&= 6(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2.\end{align}$

Comment: Yes I know that, but this just comes out of the blue so I asked this question.

Comment: This is why the site asks people posting questions to provide some context for the problem.  The identity "comes out of the blue" in what source?  Does the author have reason to assume that the reader _should know_ this already?  Is this an exam solution, a contest solution, a homework solution, a worked example in a text?  It could also be that the explication is just poorly handled by the writer.  But "the answer uses the mysterious identity" doesn't do much to explain the situation.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner If you need the context, here it is: it's at the beginning of a book concentrated on "algebraic inequalities". After the preface to the first chapter, where the author introduces that many problems can be solve by using the nonnegativity of $x^2$, this is the first example (without developing any other method). Then the author notes: the reader is supposed to memorize identities like that. I can't find better words but just "come out of the blue".

Comment: @YuxiaoXie  Perhaps then the example is being done only for illustrative purposes and a typical reader is not expected to know this identity already, but it will be explained later.  Alternatively, the author assumes (and hopefully _states_ that assumption early on) that the reader has _already_ encountered such identities.  Otherwise, I will quite agree this is "out of the blue".  But that's why we ask on this site  for clarification of the origin of problems.  What astoundingly sophisticated text _is_ this?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Well, if you really want to know, this is a text in Chinese for high school maths olympiads. This is quite a good book because it contains a lot of new methods of proving inequalities and there are many extremely hard inequality problems. HOWEVER, we call this whole book mysterious (partly because sometimes the author just multiplies all things out using something called "increment substitution". So this book just looks scary).

Comment: @YuxiaoXie  That _does_ explain something:  "olympiad" books can be _quite_ informative about useful or interesting techniques and identities, but are frequently not the best place to start if you're trying to work your way toward understanding.  There are many books I'd never ask someone to start with in order to gain acquintance with a topic.

Answer (score 0):

I give two solutions.

Solution 1:

After homogenization, it suffices to prove that
$$(a + b)^4 + (a + c)^4 + (a + d)^4 + (b + c)^4 + (b + d)^4 + (c + d)^4 \le 6(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2.$$

The Buffalo Way works. WLOG, assume that $d \le c \le b \le a$.
Let $c = d + s, b = d + s + t, a = d + s + t + r$ for $s, t, r\ge 0$. We have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{RHS} - \mathrm{LHS} &=
3 r^4+4 r^3 s+8 r^3 t+6 r^2 s^2+12 r^2 s t+12 r^2 t^2+4 r s^3\\
&\quad +12 r s^2 t +12 r s t^2+8 r t^3+3 s^4+8 s^3 t+12 s^2 t^2+8 s t^3+4 t^4.
\end{align}
We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

Solution 2:

We can use SOS (Sum of Squares) method without the identity, with the help of computer.

After homogenization, it suffices to prove that
$$(a + b)^4 + (a + c)^4 + (a + d)^4 + (b + c)^4 + (b + d)^4 + (c + d)^4 \le 6(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2.$$

We have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{RHS} - \mathrm{LHS} &= 
(-a b+a c+b d-c d)^2+\frac{1}{3} (a b+a c-2 a d-2 b c+b d+c d)^2 \\
&\quad +\frac{1}{2} (-a^2+2 a d+b^2-2 b c+c^2-d^2)^2\\
&\quad +(a b-a c-b^2+b d+c^2-c d)^2+(a^2-a b-a c+b d+c d-d^2)^2\\
&\quad +\frac{1}{6} (-3 a^2+2 a b+2 a c+2 a d-3 b^2+2 b c+2 b d-3 c^2+2 c d-3 d^2)^2.
\end{align}
We are done.